# Passing Data from Rich:PopUp Panel to Parent Window in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, popup, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a functionality where i have to pass Data selected on a Pop Up Panel (using Rich:popup) to the parent Window and display it over there.

Example - Selected some checkboxes on popup Window and storing it in a list to display that list on the parent Window.
I am not able to display the data selected on Pop up window to the parent Window in JSF2.0

Please help.

Comment: I recently asked for best-practice with popups -> "dealing with popups in JSF". Little response yet .. did you figure it out yourself?

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do that :

1. Have `valueChangeListeners` on your checkboxes in the
   `rich:popupPanel` which would set the necessary attributes and then
   `render` the element of the main/parent page with ajax
2. Have javascript `onchange` events on the checkboxes and using `jQuery` manipulate the corresponding DOM elements of main/parent page

**Which one to go for?**

Depends upon your requirements. If you just want to reflect the selection made by user in the parent window momentarily, you can opt for the javascript approach. Or if the selection affects your business logic, you need to opt for the first approach.